# How to make all or few of the choices are selected by default

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.7

Sonata admin $formMapper choice: How to make all or few of the choices are selected / checked by default.

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
  $denominationsList = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
  $formMapper->add('denominations', 'choice', array(
      'choices' => array($denominationsList),
      'multiple' => true,
      'expanded' => true
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
   $denominationsList = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
   $selectedDenominations = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
   $formMapper->add('denominations', 'choice', array(
      'choices' => array($denominationsList),
      'multiple' => true,
      'expanded' => true,
      'data' => $selectedDenominations
  ));
}
```

**Note** In `'data'` we have to give the index of the selected value. Let us say if i want to only the few values to be selected then we have to pass those values indexes. From the above example if i want 10, 40 as selected the then we have to prepare `$selectedDenominations` is like `array(0, 3)`.